How to overlay the map with a TIFF file
As shown in the code posted below, I have a .tiff file and its path is stored in pathToTIFF variable, and I want to have it overlaid on the map.
At run time, the below posted code crashes and i receive the following error:
AggregateError: Request failed

the pathToTIFF is something similar to:
C:\\\\Users\\\\Sentinel-2-L1C.tiff

How to solve this problem?
code:
attachGeoTIFFAsOverlayForPath(pathToTIFF) {
    if (pathToTIFF) {
        if (typeof pathToTIFF === 'string') {
            const geoTIFFSource = new GeoTIFF({
                sources: [
                  {
                    url: pathToTIFF,
                    overviews: ['https://openlayers.org/data/raster/no-overviews.tif.ovr'],
                  },
                ],
            });
        }
    }
}


For browser security reasons you can't load image into your app from local file.

The only way to use a local file in JavaScript is to allow the user to select it, for example drag and drop it from the user's downloads folder.  The file can then be used via an object URL or in the case of GeoTIFF as a blob.  Files must be much smaller than most online examples as the entire file will be loaded in memory.  The GeoTIFF projection will also need to be looked up if it is differs from the map view.  Basic example https://jsfiddle.net/qdL5uw8f/ (works the same ways a the this OpenLayers example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop.html)
